# Why is Pandas not adding two columns at the same time here?

Tags: python, pandas, stock

I´m currently working on a "restocker" simulator which starts with a different stock position from the actual one, receive daily inputs of the actual sales and has to do 3 tasks:

- update the stock position for all itens at all stores after today sales
- verify if the current stock position has reached the "re-stock point" (85% of the full stock position)
- compute the re-stock for all itens at all stores after the `LEAD_TIME` (each store has a different `LEAD_TIME`)

First I´m gonna laid out all the concepts you guys need to know:

- `GRID` - Can be describe as the "stock target" the max stock position.
  At the first day of operation, the stock position is equal to the `GRID` and restocking will always try to bring the stock position back the `GRID`
- To the purpose of simplification, we´ll use a fixed GRID but in reality this GRID is supposed to be dynamic and recalculated after each re-stock
- `SIM_SALES = SALES`
- `SIM_STOCK(day n) = SIM_STOCK(day n-1) - SALES(day n) + RESTOCK(day n)`
- If `SIM_STOCK - SALES <= 0` , the `SALES` of the day will be assumed as zero also.

The structure of the `DataFrame` goes something like this (example with ONE `ITEM` - ONE `STORE`) and contains the actual values:

```
INDEX      ITEM     STORE   STOCK(UN)   SALES(UN)   DAY     LEAD_TIME    GRID   
0          4058855  1000    173         0           1       5            55
1          4058855  1000    172         1           2       5            55
2          4058855  1000    163         9           3       5            55
3          4058855  1000    149         14          4       5            55
```

Analogously, our simulated grid will be like this at the day one:

```
INDEX      ITEM     STORE   STOCK(UN)   SALES(UN)   DAY     LEAD_TIME    GRID      KEY      RESTOCK      COUNTER    
 0         4058855  1000    55          0           1       5            55        False    0            0
 1         4058855  1000    0           0           2       5            55        False    0            0
 2         4058855  1000    0           0           3       5            55        False    0            0
 3         4058855  1000    0           0           4       5            55        False    0            0
```

What I´m looking for is that:

```
INDEX      ITEM     STORE   SIM_STOCK(UN)   SIM_SALES(UN)   DAY     LEAD_TIME    GRID      KEY      RESTOCK      COUNTER    
0          4058855  1000    55              0               1       5            55        False    0            0
1          4058855  1000    54              1               2       5            55        False    0            0
2          4058855  1000    45              9               3       5            55        True     0            5
3          4058855  1000    31              14              4       5            55        True     0            4
4          4058855  1000    24              7               5       5            55        True     0            3
5          4058855  1000    15              9               6       5            55        True     0            2
6          4058855  1000    19              6               7       5            55        True     10           1
7          4058855  1000    11              8               8       5            55        True     0            5
8          4058855  1000    3               8               9       5            55        True     0            4
```

I´ve come up with a solution in 3 steps:

- Keep all the values (Stock, Sales, Key and Counter) in dictionaries.
- Update all the values after current day sales
- Re-calculate all the dictionaries values

Since the code is to extensive and complicated, I published the whole notebook [where](https://github.com/strod/PANDAS) (there is a csv file included)

But the important part is that this is the actual `DataFrame` that I´m getting:

```
INDEX      ITEM     STORE   SIM_STOCK(UN)   SIM_SALES(UN)   DAY     LEAD_TIME    GRID      KEY      RESTOCK      COUNTER    
0          4058855  1000    55              0               1       5            55        False    0            0
1          4058855  1000    54              1               2       5            55        False    0            0
2          4058855  1000    45              9               3       5            55        True     0            5
3          4058855  1000    31              14              4       5            55        True     0            4
4          4058855  1000    24              7               5       5            55        True     0            3
5          4058855  1000    15              9               6       5            55        True     0            2
6          4058855  1000    9               6               7       5            55        True     10           1
7          4058855  1000    1               8               8       5            55        True     0            5
8          4058855  1000    1               0               9       5            55        True     0            4
```

The code is doing everythins is supposed to except to add `RESTOCK`. Here is the part of the code where I both add the `RESTOCK` and subtract the `SALES`:

```
DF['SIM_STOCK'] = DF.apply(lambda row:(dict_est[(row['ITEM'],row['STORE'],row['DAY']-1)]
                                          -row['SIM_SALES']
                                          +row['RESTOCK']) 
                              if row['DAY'] == CURRENT_DAY 
                              else row['SIM_STOCK'], 
                              axis=1)
```

How come Pandas is subtracting but not adding if both operations are happening in the same line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why your code does not work, but there is a much better, vectorised way to perform the calculation you wish to perform. This method may also resolve your problem.

```
DF['DICT_KEY'] = list(zip(DF['ITEM'], DF['STORE'], DF['DAY']-1))

DF['SIM_STOCK'] = np.where(DF['DAY'] == CURRENT_DAY,
                           DF['DICT_KEY'].map(dict_est) - DF['SIM_SALES'] + DF['RESTOCK'],
                           DF['SIM_STOCK'])
```

**Explanation**

- Create a `pd.Series` of tuples which is then fed as keys to
  `dict_est`.
- Use `np.where` to specify your `if / else` conditions.

Comment: This is actually 40% faster, but the result was the same. Is not adding up the `RESTOCK`. Evereything else is working properly

Comment: What do you get for `DF['RESTOCK'].dtype` ?

Comment: int64. That´s definitely not the issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually quite simple...

I was trying to grab the value from the column `DF['RESTOCK]`, as follows:

```
DF['RESTOCK'] = np.where(DF['COUNTER'] == 1, 
                       DF['DICT_RESTOCK'].map(dict_RST), 
                       0)
```

But the `DF['COUNTER']` column is updated after both `RESTOCK` and `STOCK`.

That´s the right way to grab the value:

```
DF['ABAST'] = np.where(((DF['DICT_KEY'].map(dc) == 1)&(DF['DAY'] == DIA_ATUAL))
                       |(DF['COUNTER'] == 1), 
                      DF['DICT_ABAST'].map(dict_abs), 
                      0)
```